# How do I change this code to a class or function component? Note: am new to react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
// Change this to work the same way with class or function component
      const App = () => { 
      const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date(1598051730000));
      const [mode, setMode] = useState('date');
      const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

      const onChange = (event, selectedDate) =>
        const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
        setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
        setDate(currentDate);
      };

      const showMode = currentMode => {
        setShow(true);
        setMode(currentMode);
      };

      const showDatepicker = () => {
        showMode('date');
      };

      const showTimepicker = () => {
        showMode('time');
      };

      return (
        <View>
          <View>
            // display date picker
            <Button onPress={showDatepicker} title="Show date picker!" />
          </View>
          <View>
            // Display time picker
            <Button onPress={showTimepicker} title="Show time picker!" />
          </View>
          {show && (
            <DateTimePicker
              testID="dateTimePicker"
              timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={0}
              value={date}
              mode={mode}
              is24Hour={true}
              display="default"
              onChange={onChange}
            />
          )}
        </View>
      );
    };

    export default App;
```

if i put the const variables inside render(){...} i get an Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call.
if i put them before render(){} i get an Unexpected token on the 1st const around '=', 'new', and the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `const` inside the component class

```
class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    date: new Date(1598051730000),
    mode: 'date',
    show: false
  }

  onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    const currentDate = selectedDate || this.state.date;
    this.setSate({
      show: Platform.OS === 'ios',
      date: currentDate
    })
  };

  showMode = currentMode => {
    this.setSate({
      show: true,
      mode: currentMode
    })
  };

  showDatepicker = () => {
    this.showMode('date');
  };

  showTimepicker = () => {
    this.showMode('time');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <Button onPress={this.showDatepicker} title="Show date picker!" />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Button onPress={this.showTimepicker} title="Show time picker!" />
        </View>
        {
          show && (
            <DateTimePicker
              testID="dateTimePicker"
              timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={0}
              value={this.state.date}
              mode={this.state.mode}
              is24Hour={true}
              display="default"
              onChange={onChange}
            />
          )
        }
      </View >
    )
  }
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I get an error with your code saying, '''variable showDatepicker cannot be found', which means showTimepicker is not found either

Answer (score 0):

You have written a functional component. If for some reasons you have to use the class syntax instead, then you must use the old class component state management functions, not hooks.

Something like

```
class App extends React.PureComponent {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: new Date(1598051730000),
      mod: "date",
      show: false,
    }
  }

  public onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    const currentDate = selectedDate || this.state.date;
    this.setState({
      show: Platform.OS === 'ios',
      date: currentDate,
    });
  };

  public showMode = currentMode => {
    this.setState({
      show: true,
      mode: currentMode,
    })
  };

  public showDatepicker = () => {
    this.setState({ mode: "date" });
  };

  public showTimepicker = () => {
    this.setState({ mode: "time" });
  };

  public render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          // display date picker
          <Button onPress={showDatepicker} title="Show date picker!" />
        </View>
        <View>
          // Display time picker
          <Button onPress={showTimepicker} title="Show time picker!" />
        </View>
        {show && (
          <DateTimePicker
            testID="dateTimePicker"
            timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={0}
            value={date}
            mode={mode}
            is24Hour={true}
            display="default"
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

You might also have to bind those functions in your constructor if you need them to be class members. I haven't written a component as a class in a while.

```
this.showDatepicker = this.showDatepicker.bind(this);
...
```

PS: hooks and functional components is the modern way to write React, I would keep what you have already.

Edit: btw, you can reduce the complexity of your component a bit by expressing some of the logic as an effect.

```
  const showDatepicker = () => setMode('date');

  const showTimepicker = () => setMode('time');

  // Instead of showMode
 useEffect(() => {
    setShow(true);
  }, [mode]);
```